# Flutter Segmented Button| Button Segment value consists more than 1 value

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have an example List of Objects below:

```
[
  Object(name: 'Obejct1', status: 1),
  Object(name: 'Obejct2', status: 2),
  Object(name: 'Obejct3', status: 1),
  Object(name: 'Obejct4', status: 0),
  Object(name: 'Obejct4', status: 3),
]
```

And I am trying to use the Segmented Button as a filtering widget for my app where I want 3 Button Segement in my UI which is `Button1`, `Button2`, `Button3` and wonder is it possible to achieve something as below?

```
ButtonSegment(
  value: 1, --> is it possible to assign '0' and '1' to this field?
  label: const Text('Button1')),
ButtonSegment(
  value: 2,
  label: const Text('Button2')),
ButtonSegment(
  value: 3,
  label: const Text('Button3'))
```

Comment: Do you want the buttonSegment to have both 0 and 1 as value or do this value has to change if something happens?

Comment: @AlessandroVendrame I want the Button Segment to have both 0 and 1 as value

Comment: I searched on the flutter docs and seems like the value field is dynamic, so you can actually put what you want inside of it.
The problem is that I have to understand why you have to achieve to have 2 values on the same button, can you explain me better, we can try to find out a solution, maybe playing with json objects and arrays.

So, my question is, why do u have to put 2 values inside of it, what's the purpose?

Comment: I am trying to use the Segmented Button as a filter to show different data when choosing the Button Segment. In my case, I want to have 3 Button Segment in my UI and when I pressed on the 1st Button Segment, I wanted to display Object with status 0 and 1 in my UI.

Comment: Ok, fine, so you have a method where you filter the information of your object right?

Inside of that method you can set that if the value is 1, you just show what you need to show (in this case 0 and 1 value for status).

Can you please show me the code of your 'filter method'?

Comment: you should have like a 'onSelectionChanged' method inside your segmentedButton, there you place that if the value received is == 1 then you filter also for status == 0.

Comment: i think i get your means, thanks a lot.